# Hide shipping cost in woocomerce admin with wooreer plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

On the order form it looks like this :[image]

I'm trying to hide the table ( row) where wooreer appears:

wooreer (48 km) Articulos : Cert***       33.60 €   7.06 €

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours i could see that the answer is these code:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_head_shop_order_inline_css_S' );

function admin_head_shop_order_inline_css_S() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    // Targeting WooCommerce admin single orders
    if ( in_array( $pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php'] ) && $typenow === 'shop_order' ) :
    ?><style>
    table.woocommerce_order_items .shipping {display:none;}
    </style><?php
    endif;
}
```

These code was checked and it's work in function.php theme.
With these code you can hide Shipping in the admin order.